# PHP-7.1.6 - enable with security.limit_extensions .shtml files?

Tags: php-7.1, shtml

How to enable in PHP-7.1.6, setting "security.limit_extensions", execution of .shtml files? I get error "Access to the script '/var/www/..../file.shtml' has been denied (see security.limit_extensions)" The file.shtml is following

```
<?php include ("web.php"); ?>
```

Comment: Edit your PHP configuration. If you have no option to, well, that's a problem with your host. Either rename the files or move host.

Answer (score 3):

1 - Locate the php configuration file

```
php-fpm.conf
```

2 - Edit the line for security.limit_extensions, adding the .shtml to it.

```
security.limit_extensions = .php .html .shtml
```

3 - If the line doesn't exist, just add to the file anyway

4 - Remember to reload the php service (I would recommend also restarting the server)